# Shell script to copy file from linux box to remote host with a sudo su access

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh

I have to copy a file from a linux box where i have logged in as a different user using su - username.

On the remote server i login using my unix id to switch to another user as sudo su - username. Here I enter my unixid password and become the user(since i am added to sudoers list).

Is there a way to copy a file using scp to remote host without entering password?

Please help

Comment: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an RSA key. You can generate ssh-rsa keys with the ssh-keygen command. Just run the command and it will guide you through the process. The command will create two files, a public key and a private key. The contents of the public key file should be added (>>) to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Now the private key file should be copied to the other machine, where you can use scp command in the following forms:

```
$ scp -i /the/private/key/file otheruser@otherhost:/file/to/copy /destination/path
```

or

```
$ scp -i /the/private/key/file /file/to/copy otheruser@otherhost:/destination/path
```

Note that publickey authentication must be enabled in ssh's configuration.

I hope this helps

Comment: On the remote machine, I can only login using sudo su - username. The server from which I am trying to transfer the file is also as a different user. su - username. So in the remote machine, first I login using my unix id and pass and then using sudo su -  username, change the user. How do I do this?